# Why svelte variables are visible in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm new in Svelte and i don't really know how it works yet and i'm going to need a little help.

I have this code in a .svelte file:

**{((result = student.startDate.split("T")))}**

And the HTML file, in the browser, it shows me, litteraly, the value of the variable.
The only thing I want is the JS variable gets updated but without showing it in the browser.

I tried to put that code in a function and call it (the function)
I watched several Youtube tutorials, official documentation, etc... but nothing helped me

Comment: Shouldn't do that in the template, do it in the controller.

Comment: how should i do it?

Comment: in the script tag you would do `$: let foo = getFoo()`

Comment: @chovy `$: let foo = getFoo` would be deemed as a syntax error by svelte compiler. Should be `$: foo = getFoo()`.

Comment: That's what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in the `<script>` block, with `$:` reactive statement, not in the template section.

```
$: result = student.startDate.split("T");
```

Just to be clear, `$: variable_name` will automatically let-declares the variable in the `<script>` top-level block scope. Above one-liner is equivalent to following:

```
let result; // not necessary
$: result = student.startDate.split("T");
```

Manually let-declaring variables is REQUIRED when you want to put multiple variables in one `$:` reactive block statement, because automatic let-declaration only happen if you're dealing with just one variable in `$:` statement.

```
let foo, bar, zoo; // is required!
$: {
  foo = data.foo;
  bar = data.bar + foo;
  zoo = data.zoo + bar;
}
```